# Find location of NEW number in list

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016, vba

I'm looking for a way to find where a `RAND()` number lies on a list of irrational (effectively RAND() as well) numbers from 0 to 1.

So I have a list of numbers 0.1003, 0.1984, 0.3895, 0.4506, 0.4724, 0.4856, 0.5602, 0.8542 in `A1:A8`

Then I have a `RAND()` number to check against the list. Now I've tried `RANK.AV(RAND(),A1:A8)`, but the rank functions require your lookup value to be in the list.

A simple solution would be to place my `RAND()` at the bottom of the list (`A9`) and use `RANK.AV(A9,A1:A9)`, so my number *is* included on the list, however I would have to do this for every number in my array of thousands of rand numbers, so impractical.

Perhaps there is some way I can join another cell onto an array without actually placing it adjacent?

Eg, for a RAND() in B1, I could write in C1:

`=RANK.AV(B1,ARRAY.JOIN(A1:A8,B1))`, but I've tried a few ways (&,+) and can't achieve this array joining function, so I thought I'd ask for help! Perhaps a macro or UDF is required?

Comment: If your list is sorted (as your sample is) then you can use `Match` with the final parameter `True` to get the position of your test value

Comment: I'm pretty sure you would need a bit of VBA to insert the new number into the list and move the ones after it down by one place

Comment: Apologies for the poor wording; I do not actually need to place the RAND() value in the list, only to find where (numerically) its place in the list would be. I've edited the wording slightly

Comment: In that case, see @Chris Neilsen's comment: Match will give you the position of the element immediately before your new random number which you gives the rank. It seems only fair to let him give this as an answer if he wants to.

Comment: BTW ties are extremely unlikely with real numbers if rand() is based on a decent algorithm, but you could code it in if you wanted to be sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry @Chris, I'm sure this is what you meant in your comment:-

```
=IF(B1<A1,1,MATCH(B1,$A$1:$A$10)+1)
```

where your new random number is in B1 and your existing list in A1:A10, sorted in ascending order. Where the new number is less than the first entry in the list, this would be a special case: otherwise, you could allow for it by placing a zero in A1 and moving the pseudo-random numbers down which would simplify the formula to

```
=MATCH(B1,A$1:A$10)
```

[image]

If you wanted to allow for ties, you could correct for it:-

```
=IF(B1<A1,1,MATCH(B1,$A$1:$A$10)+1)-COUNTIF($A$1:$A$10,B1)/2
```

or just

```
=MATCH(B1,$A$1:$A$10)-COUNTIF($A$1:$A$10,B1)/2
```

with a zero in A1.

I'm assuming that ranking is from 1=smallest to 8=largest if there are 8 numbers: you can easily change it by subtracting the rank from count(A$1:A$10)+2 or  count(A$1:A$10)+1 if the zero is included.

Comment: yeah Tom that's what I meant. Might be worth adding the requirement that the search range needs to be sorted.

Comment: Thanks - have embellished my answer a bit.

Answer (score 0):

This could do your trick:

```
=RANK.AVG(INDEX(A1:A8,RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNT(A1:A8))),A1:A8)
```

This ranks a random choice out of random numbers.

Comment: Almost, but not quite; your approach picks a random number from the list, giving all numbers equal weighting. However my list is not evenly spaced, so the chances of being ranked between two widely spaced numbers should be proportionally higher than between two numbers much closer together. This is a necessity for my purposes, and is overlooked by this approach.

Comment: If i got you right this might be your solution `=RANK.AVG(VLOOKUP(RAND(),A1:A8,1,TRUE),A1:A8)`. And this is basically the same as it makes a random number act as the number in a list.

Comment: Actually, I missed cases when number is higher than max or lower than min making the correct formula like this: `=IFERROR(RANK.AVG(VLOOKUP(B1,A1:A8,1,TRUE),A1:A8),IF(B1>MAX(A1:A8),1,COUNT(A1:A8)+1))`. I hope this one is the one you need.